# C# Get page type name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get a Page's type, to assign it to a div's id.

I tried:

```
<div id="<%= this.Page.GetType().Name %>" class="website-content">
```

But I got it in the form

> master_page_name_aspx

I also tried

```
<div id="<%= this.Page.GetType().GetType().Name %>" class="website-content">
```

but it produced `RuntimeType`

I'd like to get, for example, `EditUser`, or whatever the page web form class is called.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is your first and second example different? They look identical to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is probably:

```
<div id="<%= this.Page.GetType().BaseType.Name %>" class="website-content">
```

Since `GetType().GetType()` will only return the same type, regardless of how many times you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `<%= GetType().BaseType.Name %>` on a default WebApp in VS2010 gave me the class for the page.